# How to know if Crontab is working?

Tags: python, shell, cron

I'm trying to run a simple crontab (on mac OSX Terminal)

My cronjob thing looks like this:

```
* * * * * /Users/tanavya.dimri/Documents/cron.sh
```

cron.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/tanavya.dimri/Documents
python hello.py > empty
```

And hello.py is simply

```
print "Hello"
```

When I just run `sh cron.sh` it works. Empty, which is just an empty text file, does get changed to "Hello".
However, I don't really know if it's working with crontab because the file doesn't change after I remove the hello from it.

Comment: Try after removing the file. If the crontab runs, it should create it.

Comment: The con will not know settings from your `.profile` of `.bashrc`. Maybe you are missing something, such as a change to PATh so pythom can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try after removing the file. If the crontab runs, it should create it

There is a way to check if your crontab job ran successfully. Note that the log file references in the cron commands are given using full paths not relative paths. You need to make sure that your scripts use full paths or cd to the correct working directory.

[Crontab Log: How to Log the Output of My Cron Script](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/crontab-log/)

> Let us say that you’ve added the backup.sh to your crontab as shown
>   below to execute it at midnight every day.

```
$ crontab -e 59 23 * * * /home/john/bin/backup.sh
```

> To verify whether the this job got executed successfully or not, check
>   the /var/log/cron file, which contains information about all the cron
>   jobs that gets executed in your system. As you see from the following
>   output, john’s cron job got executed succesfully.

```
$ tail /var/log/cron
Oct  8 22:00:00 dev-db crond[18340]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /home/root/bin/system_check &)
Oct  8 23:00:00 dev-db crond[20348]: (oracle) CMD (/bin/sh /home/oracle/bin/cleanup.sh &)
Oct  8 23:59:00 dev-db crond[20399]: (john) CMD (/bin/sh /home/john/bin/backup.sh &)
```

> Cron log contains the following information:
>
> Timestamp – The date and time when the cron job was executed
>
> Hostname – The hostname of the server (For example, dev-db)
>
> The cron deamon name and the PID. For example, crond[20399]
>
> Username – The username under which this cron job got executed. For
>   example, john.
>
> CMD – Anything following this is the real command that got executed at
>   that time.
>
> If there are any echo statements inside the backup.sh, you might want
>   to log those into a file. In general, if the backup.sh cron script
>   throws any output (including errors), you might want to log those to a
>   log file. To do this, modify the crontab entry and add the output and
>   error redirection as shown below.

```
$ crontab -e 59 23 * * * /home/john/bin/backup.sh > /home/john/logs/backup.log 2>&1
```

> In the above:
>
> /home/john/logs/backup.log indicates that the standard output of the
>   backup.sh script will be redirected to the backup.log file.
>
> 2>&1 indicates that the standard error (2>) is redirected to the same
>   file descriptor that is pointed by standard output (&1).
>
> So, both standard output and error will be redirected to
>   /home/john/logs/backup.log

Comment: @AlexStone did you use the full path of where you want the file to ensure that it is put in the correct place?

Comment: @AlexStone i added some more detail what my need to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, however when I do tail /var/log/cron I get "No such file or directory". But I removed the "empty" file, added chmod 700 permissions to the file by doing chmod 700 cron.sh, and now it's working. Thanks though ;)

Answer (score 3):

By default cronjobs logged into `/var/log/syslog`

So you can simply grep that log CRON and checkout your job execution:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have sufficient permissions for your cron.sh file.

```
chmod 755 cron.sh
```

Then modify your crontab to run periodically (i.e. 1 min):

```
 */1 * * * * /Users/tanavya.dimri/Documents/cron.sh
```